# how cases get evaluated in switch statements (C)

Tags: c, switch-statement, break

I'm corrently learning C, and I'm allready familiar with basic programming concepts
I have a question about switch statement
for ex in the following code

```
for(int i =0 ; i<20; i++){

        switch(i){
        case 0: i+=5; /*label 1*/
        case 1: i+=2; /*label 2*/
        case 5: i+=5; /*label 3*/
        default : i+=4; /*label 4*/
        }
        printf("%d\t",i);
    }
```

the output is 16   21

that means that case at label 1 is executed first, then since there is no break, label 2, 3 and 4 are also executed, the question is that if label 1 is executed then value of i is updated to 5, does other cases check the condition first (if i =1 or 5 ) then execute or it just execute anything without checking?

Comment: my question is about the evaluation of cases, I want to know if ( in absence of break) case with label 2 will check if i is equale to 1 before executing or it will be executed without checking

Comment: Basically `switch/case` works like this: the expression in the switch statement is evaluated, and then the program continues at the corresponding case label or at the default label if none of the case labels matches the result of the expression. That's all. The case lables are just labels, no check whatsoever is performed elsewhere than in the `switch`.

Comment: that make sense, thank you all

Comment: debug the code and you'll see the issue immediately. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/995714), [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: thanks,
for anyone reading this, those links were a great use for me, I recommend that you take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very good question, and actually reveals the internals of the `switch` statement in C and C++, which can sometimes be confused with cascading `if-else` statements.

The `switch` statement in C/C++ works as follows:

- (1) first it evaluates the expression presented as a condition in the `switch` statement
- (2) stores the result on the stack or using a general-purpose register
- (3) using that result it attempts to jump to the corresponding case statement with the minimum comparisons possible by using a jump-table (when one can be built).

It is because of (1) and (2) that the `switch` you created is not behaving the way you may expect, and it doesn't reevaluate the initial expression during the execution of the `case` statements.

In contrast with cascading `if-else` statements, your `case` statements are essentially blocks of instructions compiled in sequential order, referenced by a jump table as mentioned at (3). Once the execution reaches a `case` statement, it will automatically cascade over the next `case` statements if `break` is not encountered. The `break` actually instructs the compiler to *jump over* the switch statement and stop executing the `case` statements.

Check out this commented disassembly of your switch statement, just to have a better grip of what's happening under the hood:

```
   0x56555585 <+56>:    mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax       ;<--- store "i" (the switch condition) into EAX
   0x56555588 <+59>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax              ;<--- check "case 1"
   0x5655558b <+62>:    je     0x5655559a <main+77>   ;<--- jump if equal to "case 1"
   0x5655558d <+64>:    cmp    $0x5,%eax              ;<--- check "case 5"
   0x56555590 <+67>:    je     0x5655559e <main+81>   ;<--- jump if equal to "case 5" 
   0x56555592 <+69>:    test   %eax,%eax              ;<--- check "case 0"
   0x56555594 <+71>:    jne    0x565555a2 <main+85>   ;<--- jump if not equal to "default"
   0x56555596 <+73>:    addl   $0x5,-0x10(%ebp)       ;<--- case 0
   0x5655559a <+77>:    addl   $0x2,-0x10(%ebp)       ;<--- case 1
   0x5655559e <+81>:    addl   $0x5,-0x10(%ebp)       ;<--- case 5
   0x565555a2 <+85>:    addl   $0x4,-0x10(%ebp)       ;<--- default
```

*Note: this is built with `-m32 -O0` gcc options to use 32bit code which is much easier to read, and disable optimizations.*

You can clearly see that after the jump is made (to any case statement) there is no further reevaluation of `i` (`-0x10(%ebp)`). Also, when the case is executed, it automatically cascades to the next one if no `break` is used.

Now, you may ask yourself *why this odd behavior* and the answer is at (3): to *jump to the corresponding case statement with the minimum comparisons possible*.

The `switch` statements in C/C++ show their true strength when the number of `case` statements really scales up and especially when the spread between the values used for the `case` statements is constant.

For example, let's assume we have a large `switch` statement with 100 `case` values, with a constant spread of `1` between case values and that the switch expression (`i`) evaluates to `100` (last `case` in the `switch`):

```
switch (i) {
 case 1: /*code for case 1*/ break;
 case 2: /*code for case 2*/ break;
 [...]
 case 99: /*code for case 99*/ break;
 case 100: /*code for case 100*/ break;
}
```

If you used cascading `if-else` statements you would get 100 comparisons, but this `switch` can obtain the same result using just a couple of instructions, in this order:

- first: the compiler will index all the `case` statements in a jump table
- second: it will evaluate the condition in the `switch` and store the result (i.e.: fetch `i`)
- third: it calculates the corresponding index in the jump table based on the result (i.e.: decrement `i` by `1`, the first `case` statement, results in index 99)
- fourth, it jumps directly to the corresponding `case` without any further operation

The same will apply if your case values have a spread of `2`:

```
switch (i) {
 case 1: /*code for case 1*/ break;
 case 3: /*code for case 3*/ break;
 [...]
 case 99: /*code for case 99*/ break;
 case 101: /*code for case 101*/ break;
}
```

Your compiler should detect this spread too and after subtracting the first case value (which is `1`) will divide by `2` to obtain the same index for the jump table.

This complicated inner-workings of the `switch` statement makes it a very powerful tool in C/C++ when you want to branch your code based on a value you can only evaluate at run-time, and when that value belongs to a set that is evenly spread, or at least, groups of values with an even spread.

When the `case` values don't have an even spread, the `switch` becomes less efficient and it starts to perform similarly to if we have used cascading `if-else` instead.

Comment: your answer left no questions to ask 
is there any sources or books that explains in such details ?

Answer (score 2):

In the labeled parts of the switch statement there are no break statements

```
for(int i =0 ; i<20; i++){

    switch(i){
    case 0: i+=5; /*label 1*/
    case 1: i+=2; /*label 2*/
    case 5: i+=5; /*label 3*/
    default : i+=4; /*label 4*/
    }
    printf("%d\t",i);
}
```

So when `i` is equal to `0` (in the first iteration of the loop) then all these statements

```
    case 0: i+=5; /*label 1*/
    case 1: i+=2; /*label 2*/
    case 5: i+=5; /*label 3*/
    default : i+=4; /*label 4*/
```

are executed sequentially after passing the control to the case label `0:` and `i` becomes equal to `16`.

You can imagine the switch statement in the first iteration of the loop the following way

```
goto Label0;

Label0: i+=5; /*label 1*/
Label1: i+=2; /*label 2*/
Label5: i+=5; /*label 3*/
Labeldefault : i+=4; /*label 4*/
```

Labels are just labels. They do not execute any code. After evaluating the expression in the switch statement

```
switch(i)
```

the control is passed to the corresponding labeled statement and all the following statements are executed sequentially if there is no jump statement.

Then in the third expression of the for loop `i` is incremented and becomes equal to `17`.

So in the next iteration of the for loop the control at once is passed to the label `default` and `i` becomes equal to `21`.

Comment: I understand that when i = 0 label 1 is executed, that makes i = 5, after that all other cases will be executed as well, without checking if i = 1 or 5 ?

Comment: @DJEBARRARABAHABDERRAZAK See my updated post. The check of the expression is done only in the switch itself. Labels are only labels. They do not execute any code.